# Verify AD User Password

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I understand that no secure application has the ability to retrieve a password by using a mere script, but I was wondering if it's possible to at least verify if an entered password is correct using PowerShell.

I need to build a script that will allow a user to change his AD password, but for that to be possible, he/she needs to enter his current password. I will then perform a check to see if the current entered password is correct before proceeding.

I tried to verify the current attributes that a `Get-ADUser` can return, but i can't find anything useful to this.

Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know where I found it but this works for me

```
# Validate credentials
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement")
$principalContext = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext([System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Domain, '<yourdomain>')
$principalContext.ValidateCredentials('<user>', '<password>')
```

Comment: You are welcome. Note that I would expect your script to have failed anyway if you can't get the correct current credentials for the user unless you somehow run the script as an AD admin user. Note that I think that would be a bad idea ;)